# Modified on X Approved on - how to create two different columns

Tags: last-modified-date

I am working on list of tasks for my team. And met with couple of troubles.
I need to track date of completion and after that its approval. Unfortunately when I have tried to create "completion date" with this formula:

```
=IF( [Task Status]="Completed"
     ;DATE(
           YEAR([Modified on])
           ;MONTH([Modified on])
           ;DAY([Modified on])
          )
   )
```

or another one

```
=IF(
    [Task Status]="Completed"
    ;[Modified on]
    ;"")
```

the date will change anytime when someone made any change. Even when approver (manager) approves the task. It automatically changes the completion date to last modifying.
I am getting lost. I've tried InfoPath, do scan of billions chats in internet but without any clever solution.
Could someone help with that? How to lock/fixed "completion date" when owner of task change the status to "Completed"?
I am intermediate user of InfoPath, beginner of SP Designer/workflows but loser in any coding (Java, C#,...).
Appreciate any help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas are re-calculated on every Item change

So the only way to get a fixed Date, is to use a Workflow that writes a date to a [Modified On] (Date)Field, and only if that Date field is empty
You can not use Formulas for this.

Workflow:

- Is [Modified On] Empty ?

  - Is [Tasks Status] Completed ?

    - Then Set [Modified On] to Today()

Comment: Nice, workflow sounds better to me. Just was nor sure if it is possible.

Comment: May I please ask for some manual or detailed description of that workflow?

Comment: Build this with a SharePoint Designer Workflow

Comment: Many thanks Danny for your help. But I dont know how to create it :(
Would you think you will be able to put screen of that workflow from Sp Designer? Realy appreciate it.

Comment: You are trying to run before you can walk. Start by learning SharePoint Workflows. Here is a one hour YouTube course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccfBQQRTWFk